# Is there a way to aggregate data from columns in Excel?

Tags: excel

would you please advise if there's a way in Excel to aggregate data from specified columns of another sheet?
I got 3 columns in sheet A, where data is dynamical - changed manually on a regular basis. I'd like to gather these manual entries in a separate sheet B, exclude duplicates and use it for further vlookups.
I've tried Power Query and it's now possible to capture the current state of 3 columns from sheet A, but I can't come up with solution to aggregate and remove duplicates within data refresh.
Appreciate your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to advanced editor for the query, there are options to remove duplicates and aggregate:

Removing Duplicates:
[image: remove duplicates]

Three different ways to aggregate (depending on your aggregation goals):

1. Group By: (for grouping based on a category or count)
   [image: groupby]
2. Merge Columns: (for making a "comma-separated" list of values between two or more columns)
   [image: Merge Columns]
3. Custom Column: (for calculated column such as a SUM on multiple columns into one)
   [image: Custom Column]

Comment: Thank you for the advise, however the aggregate options you've provided don't work for me / don't perform the expected operation >> what I got is 2 sheets - one with 3 columns which are populated manually, another one shall only accumulate data from the first sheet into its own 3 columns (e.g. after every refresh of the query). The key here is to append new data to the second sheet, without harm to the "historical" data = e.g. data from previous refresh

Comment: @max Two options: A) You'll need a helper query to copy and append into another sheet. B) Open a new workbook, import into that workbook from the original using power query, and then do you changes from there. This is why seeing more detail in your request is extremely important, as it will help us help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate all the input! Meanwhile, I've covered this functionality with the following macro and linked it to a button inside the report - it's primitive, but does the job:

```
Sub DatanetComments()

'Definition of variables for the last row of the columns we work with:
Dim wLastRow As Long
Dim bxLastRow As Long
Dim byLastRow As Long
Dim aLastRowComments As Long
Dim cLastRowComments As Long


Sheets("Datanet").Select

'Check if any filter is on, remove any filters:
If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If

'Define last rows for the columns of interest:
wLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp).Row
bxLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 76).End(xlUp).Row
byLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 77).End(xlUp).Row
aLastRowComments = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
cLastRowComments = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

'Selection of columns from Datanet, copy-paste to the end of Comments existing list, removal of duplicates:
Range("W2:W" & wLastRow & ",BX2:BX" & bxLastRow & ",BY2:BY" & byLastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Comments 2.0").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("A:C").Select
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```